# Binding Grid Column With Particular Column having different value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have following database table>>

```
TradeNo | Buy_Sell | Trade_Qty | Market_Price

205412     1           50            300   

205487     2           30            350 

208754     1           20            200
```

In this table there is column Buy_Sell. Buy=1 , Sell =2

When I bind the grid, values are showing as it is.

But , I wanted to show them in grid as >

```
    TradeNo | Buy_Sell | Trade_Qty | Market_Price

    205412     Buy           50            300   

    205487     Sell          30            350 

    205487     Buy           20            200
```

How can i do that?

I have simply bound the grid with following code>

```
try
{
  da=new SqlDataAdapter("Select TradeNo, Buy_Sell,TradeQty,Market_Price from tradeFile",conn);
  DataSet ds=new DataSet();
  da.Fill(ds);
  gvTrade.dataSource=ds.Tables[0]; 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

What Should be the changes in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Buy_Sell` is a foreign key column referencing a "Buy_Sell_Types" table, change your query to something like the following (adding a join):

```
SELECT TradeNo, Buy_Sell_Types.Name, TradeQty, Market_Price 
FROM tradeFile
JOIN Buy_Sell_Types ON tradeFile.Buy_Sell = Buy_Sell_Types.PrimaryKey
```

Otherwise, you could transform the data in code using LINQ:

```
try
{
    da=new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TradeNo, Buy_Sell, TradeQty, Market_Price FROM tradeFile", conn);
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    gvTrade.dataSource = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
             .Select(d => new 
             {
                 TradeNo = d.Field<int>("TradeNo"),
                 Buy_Sell = d.Field<int>("Buy_Sell") == 1 ? "Buy" : "Sell",
                 TradeQty = d.Field<int>("TradeQty"),
                 Market_Price = d.Field<double>("MarketPrice")
             }); 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: but Buy_Sell is not primary key

Comment: So there is no Buy_Sell_Types table?

Comment: Yes, you can utilise LINQ on data tables, the .AsEnumerable() call on the DataTable enables this.

Comment: Its not giving any error[exception] , but its not showing any result in the grid also @Oliver

Comment: Its not giving any error[exception] , but its not showing any result in the grid also